# How compare two Git branches in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am not sure if it's possible to compare master branch (or any other) with the current feature branch like `GIT` does.

I want the Diff between two branches (master and feature branch) so that I can compare the diff before merging.I find Git UI less user friendly. As in AS I can traverse through code and change it right there.

I have found an option where I can compare any branch with my current local branch (that seem's like a solution to me but when I used it I got very confused).

[image: SS!]

[image: SS2]

`Compare with current` feature of AS compare two brach with specific selected commit.

While what I required is compare latest of both. (head of feature branch with head of master).Like we get in merge request of Git.

P.S- I thought of selecting all commit's to get the whole diff but it give a very different result something mix of all the diff's.

Want to get something like this.

[image: SS#]

Comment: Try `git difftool master..featurebranch` from terminal .You can use meld as diff tool for UI

Comment: It's not possible to do it using GIT UI? @Vibhas

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I compare by right clicking my 'app' directory --> git --> compare with branch

[image: See entire diff]

Comment: This seems to work pretty well.  Provides a list of changed files, and you can look at the differences within this files too.  You can even merge the differences one-by-one.  You can even start by selecting the base project and see ALL the files.

Answer (score 2):

There is some trick

1.Change the view to **Project** in Android Studio.
[image]

2. selecting `Git` and `Compare with Branch`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I check code before I merge it into master:

1.) Create and check out 'master' branch or one that has the same code as what's in master. (This can be done via the Terminal tab in Android Studio.)

```
git checkout master
```

OR

```
git checkout master_code_review_branch
```

2.) Run this command in the terminal to copy the commits from the branch you wish to compare (ex. ORIGIN/BRANCH_TO_MERGE) into the branch you've checked out. It will not commit.

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff ORIGIN/BRANCH_TO_MERGE
```

3.) Now you can see all the individual changes in Android Studio by checking the "Version Control" tab or in the "commit" confirmation menu.

When done, you can "Abort Merge" in Android studio UI or via this terminal command:
    git reset --merge --hard

More details here if you're interested:
https://medium.com/@mkutlev/pull-request-review-with-intellij-idea-or-android-studio-e60fbb3e3639

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear a direct way. But there is a way if you look closely.

- No need to make a new branch, if you can spot a branch which has
  last commit on a previous time compared to the commit you want to
  compare with.

  If not, just make a local branch by title of your choice.
- Use "**Compare with Branch...**"
- **All the commits between the selected branch head appear in the table**. So spot your needed commit here.
- Use the tabs titled **Log** or **Files** for comparing the revisions better.