# Intellij: Branch Compare(Show Diff with working tree changed)?

Tags: intellij-idea, compare

Hello I am trying to use the classic branch compare that didnt utilize the "Changes" menu.

That one that had it's own popup with file side by side comparison.

I am finding myself using the 2023 version but the view/behavior is different and not to my liking...

Anyone know if its possible to use the old classic view ?

[image]

looked more or less like this

Update : Found a view with what I am trying to see - https://youtu.be/yo-HrNkxfyI?t=49

More example with screen shots in SO question : [Find all changes between two branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589233/find-all-changes-between-two-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is no more modal window when you are invoking "Show diff with working tree".

Now this modal window placed in toolwindow under "Changes" tab.
There is  no option to bring the old behavior back, regrettably.